# Does this PDE have analytic solutions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I would like to know whether this P.D.E is solvable and if yes, for which values of $a$.

$$
2 (y \cos a + x \sin a) - 4 (y \sin a - x \cos a) f - 2 (y \cos a + x \sin a) f^2 + (x^2 \cos a - 2 x y \sin a - y^2 \cos a) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - (x^2 \sin a + 2 x y \cos a - y^2 \sin a) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0
$$

Where $f = f(x, y)$. I have tried to solve it for the case where $a=0$,

$$
2 y + 4 x f - 2 y f^2 + (x^2-y^2) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}- 2 x y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0
$$

on MATHEMATICA but after 3 hours it gave me no result.

Then I utilised the method of characteristics and expressed the $a=0$ case as a system of three ODES

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = (x^2 - y^2)
\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = (-2xy)
\\
\frac{df}{dt} = 2yf^2 - 2y - 4xf
$$
but MATHEMATICA still gave me no results. So I suspect that this PDE might not have an analytic solution. 
Is this PDE solvable, and if not could you please indicate a reference which indicates which cases of PDES are non solvable? I am only interested in Analytic solutions.

Any kind of help will be most appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might help if you write out the equation in conventional mathematical form, so we don't have to decipher the Mathematica commands.